# Q: Combine 2 queries into 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently I have 3 tables:

1. User table

   username | firstname | lastname
2. Course table

   course id | course name | course date | course description
3. Attendance table

   course id | username

User table contain information on the users.
Course table contains information on courses.
There are multiple courses with the same name, but different date. 
Attendance table contains the attendance of users for the course.

I am given a list of username and a course name. I have to find the first and last name of each user and the latest date each user taken the course.

currently I first use this query to find the first and last name.

```
Select firstname, lastname from user where username in (<user list>)
```

Next, I loop through the results of previous query and take the first result of the following query:

```
select date from attendance, course 
where attendance.course_id in (select course_id from course where course_name = <course>) 
and username = <username> and attendance.course_id = course.course_id 
order by course_date desc
```

The result of all this is that for n number of users, I have to run n+1 number of queries. I would like to reduce this to a single query, any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
Select 
  u.firstname
 ,u.lastname
 ,(Select Max(c.course_date) 
   from Attendance a
   join Course c on
   c.course_id = a.course_id
   where
   a.username = u.username
   and c.course_name = <course>
) latest_date
from user u
where u.username in (<user list>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood the question:

```
select u.firstname, 
       u.lastname, 
       max(c.course_date) max_course_date
from t_attendance a join t_course c on c.course_id = a.course_id
                    join t_user u on c.username = u.username
where a.username in ('user1', 'user2', ...)
  and c.course_name in ('course1', 'course2', ...) 
group by u.firstname, 
         u.lastname;
```

`WHERE` clause might need adjustment, depending on how you get list of usernames and course names.